# Bootstrap script locking up page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, bootstrap-5, visual-studio-2022, pageload

After a while, so I don't know what starts this off, my browser will have the following problem with my net 3.1 MVC site while in Visual Studio 2022 (debug or release), I switched from Chrome to Edge and it worked for a bit, but the same error appeared later,

I just tried it in FireFox and it is working there currently

I reset the settings in Edge and that did nothing

On the deployed version it is working just fine, even in the same browser

If I roll back to pervious versions of my site that never had this problem before, the error is still there

Error:

When I try to load

```
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

on a razor page it locks the page in an infinite loading loop(it loads everything before the script is called), never failing but locking up the page and I cannot access the Dev Tools for the webpage

I almost don't know where to begin trying to debug this problem

I have removed this script line and everything else loads just fine

I have removed the base files, and as you would expect it cannot find the files to reference and logs the failure to the Dev console, but the page loads.

I have updated to the latest bootstrap version

I updated to the latest visual studio 2022 version

I have tried to only load the script and it locks up

I'm going to start rolling back versions of visual studio now, just want to get this out here.

Comment: Ok I rolled back to Visual Studio version 17.5.1 and the site started working again, however this is where my problem started in the first place so any ideas would be great. If i had to guess it is a visual studio problem, maybe my local install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the exact same issue as you today, the only difference was my project is a .net 6 application.

I was also on version 17.5.1 of Visual Studio. Version 17.5.2 is now available and after upgrading to this, this fixed the issue for me. Hope it does for you too!